# Unix - Using find to List all .html files. (Do not use shell wildcards or the ls command)

Tags: regex, shell, unix, find

I've tried `'find -name .html$'`, `'find -name .html\>'`.
None worked.

I'd like to know why these two are wrong and what's the right one to use with no wildcards?

Comment: `find -type f | grep -e 'html$'`. What's wrong with using wildcards? `find -name '*.html'`.

Comment: @Zoe, in future when you have seemingly arbitrary constraints, please explain the source of the constraint so that people may provide appropriate help. Is this a bar bet? An online quiz? Or do you have some specific engineering reason to avoid wildcard characters?

Comment: It's just an exercise. I guess the limitation is to avoid using 'easy pass' but understand the other choices out there. Thanks for suggestion!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you needed was

```
find -name '*.html'
```

Or for regex:

```
find -regex '.*/.*\.html'
```

To ignore case, use -iname or -iregex:

```
find -iname '*.html'
find -iregex '.*/.*\.html'
```

Manual for `-name`:

```
   -name pattern
          Base of file name (the path with the leading directories
          removed) matches shell pattern pattern.  The metacharacters
          (`*', `?', and `[]') match a `.' at the start of the base name
          (this is a change in findutils-4.2.2; see section STANDARDS CON‐
          FORMANCE below).  To ignore a directory and the files under it,
          use -prune; see an example in the description of -path.  Braces
          are not recognised as being special, despite the fact that some
          shells including Bash imbue braces with a special meaning in
          shell patterns.  The filename matching is performed with the use
          of the fnmatch(3) library function.   Don't forget to enclose
          the pattern in quotes in order to protect it from expansion by
          the shell.
```

Comment: But isn't it shell wildcard

Comment: @Zoe It is but the pattern is interpreted inside `find` since it's already quoted with single quotes. Also, in Windows/DOS those are called wildcards, but in Linux or UNIX, it is mostly known as `glob` patterns. See my update by the way for the info.

Comment: find -regex '.*/.*\.html' What's .*/.* doing here?

Answer (score 5):

```
find . -name '*.html'
```

You have to single quote the wildcard to keep the shell from globbing it when passing it to find.

Comment: But isn't it wildcard?

Comment: Since it is quoted, it isn't a shell wildcard. It is a `find` wildcard.

Comment: can you explain me the difference in detail? Thanks!

Comment: A command-line parameter like `*.html` is interpreted by the shell. A command-line parameter like `'*.html'` is passed, uninterpreted, to the command. In this instance, `find` uses `*` in a similar, but not identical, manner as the shell does. As a more obvious example, consider `echo '***HELLO!***'`. The `*` characters in that command are most certainly not wildcards, they are simply parameters to the `echo`.

Answer (score 2):

You want

`find . -name "*.html"`

Find uses emacs regex by default, not the posix you are probably used to.

Comment: what's the difference between using "" and ''? Thanks!

Comment: In this case, there is no difference, in general using double quotes would allow you to abstract this find into `"find . -name "*.$EXTENSION"` and allow you to define the environment variable $EXTENSION elsewhere. Single quotes would not allow this.

Comment: @Zoe -  "*Enclosing characters in single quotes (`'`) preserves the literal value of each character within the quotes.*", and "*Enclosing characters in double quotes (`"`) preserves the literal value of all characters within the quotes, with the exception of `$`, `\``, `\ `, and, when history expansion is enabled, `!`.*" -- [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Single-Quotes)

Comment: I am deeply amused by your referring to POSIX basic regular expressions as "emacs regex" and contrasting them with "posix [regex]" by which I assume you mean POSIX *extended* regular expressions and/or the even more extended (but *not* POSIX-standardized, and technically not even "regular expressions" anymore) Perl regexes.

Comment: @Zack - I was merely reciting from the find manpage, but I am glad to have caused you much amusement: "-regextype type ... Currently implemented  types  are  emacs (this is the default)"

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a couple things here. First of all the path. If you are searching in the local path, use `.` For example: `find .` will list every file and directory recursively in the current directory. Second a `*` is a wildcard. So to find all the `.html` files in the current directory, try

```
find . -name *.html
```